# Ctree in R: how optimal is the optimal split point?

Tags: cart, party

Hi I’m fairly new to using decion trees. I understand that to find the best split points, the ctree algorithm maximises a certain test statistic. I am interested to inspect the values of the test statistic for all possible split points, so that I can gain insight in how optimal the exact split point is.

As some background, in my data the ctree algorithm for variables Y ~ X returned an optimal binary split at X = 2.5. Indeed this creates two groups with different Y values. Yet it seems as if splitting the data at X = 2.4 or 2.6 gives practically equal results. I’d like to assess this, for instance by plotting the test statistic over the different split points.

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible check but, unfortunately, `ctree()` does not include this information in its output as this would potentially require a lot of storage on larger data sets. But you can compute the information "by hand" using the `coin` package, see below for a worked example.

Moreover, you could assess the stability of the tree and the estimated split points by bootstrapping. This *is* available out of the box in the `stablelearner` package and in my opinion the more comprehensive check.

But first about the statistics for the split point. As a simple example consider a tree for the `cars` data:

```
library("partykit")
ct <- ctree(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
plot(ct)
```

[image: ctree]

Thus, the first split is `speed <= 17". This can be found by computing a two-sample`independence_test()`with the`coin` package for every possible split point:

```
library("coin")
sp <- 8:23
st <- sapply(sp, function(split)
  statistic(independence_test(dist ~ factor(speed <= split), data = cars))
)
plot(sp, st, type = "b")
abline(v = sp[which.max(st)], lty = 2)
```

[image: coin]

Alternatively, you can bootstrap the learning data and re-fit the tree on every bootstrap sample. This is what `stabletree()` from the `stablelearner` package offers along with nice functions to summarize and visualize the variation in the resulting split points. Here:

```
library("stablelearner")
sb <- stabletree(ct)
plot(sb)
```

[image: stabletree]

Thus, most bootstrap samples lead to splits points that are very close to the two split points from the original tree (`ct`).